# Trouble sending emails with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to find a way to send a simple confirmation email from CodeIgniter, but it is not working and I have looked for days and haven't found any answers that worked.

my `email.php` file is:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
 * Configuration file for Email library
 */
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['smtp_timeout'] = 5;
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 587;
$config['smtp_user'] = $ENV['*****'];
$config['smtp_pass'] = $ENV['*****'];

?>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Undefined index: [My Mandrill Username] (in the config/email.php file)
Undefined index: [My Mandrill API KEY] (in the config/email.php file)
```

Comment: Why do people not read error messages? It’s telling you in plain English: `Undefined index: [My Mandrill Username] (in the config/email.php file)`. So define it in **config/email.php**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Get rid of `$_ENV` and replace it with just a string of the username
  and API key in the `email.php` file.

**Change this**:

```
$config['smtp_user'] = $_ENV['*****'];
$config['smtp_pass'] = $_ENV['*****'];
```

**To**:

```
$config['smtp_user'] = '*****';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '*****';
```

- Add this code in the signup_validation method.

Load the email config file:

```
$this->load->config('email');
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is irrelevant to the problem as the config file should be loaded from `email` library. (`$this->load->config(<config file for mandrill>`) which should define something like

```
<?php
     $config['mandrill_api_key'] = your_key
?>
```